# heroku и ffmpeg. ошибка No such file

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, heroku

Закинул python телеграмм бота на heroku.

heroku я добавил buildpack: https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest

При работе скрипта (пытаюсь склеить видео и аудио дорожки) вылетает ошибка.

No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg -i video_0.mp4 -i audio_0.mp3 -c copy output_0.mp4'

Причем файлы в директории есть.
На моет ПК все работает исправно.

Comment: Покажите свой скрипт, в нём явно какая-то ошибка

Answer (score 1):

> Причем файлы в директории есть.

ffmpeg лежит в той же папке? Тогда команда должна быть

```
./ffmpeg -i video_0.mp4 -i audio_0.mp3 -c copy output_0.mp4
```

А если не в ней, то надо убедиться, что ffmpeg доступен из консоли

> No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg -i video_0.mp4 -i audio_0.mp3 -c copy output_0.mp4'

Если это прям точное сообщение об ошибке, то очень странно, что вместо имени файла выведена вся команда - возможно, ты используешь не ту функцию для её вызова или заключаешь её в лишние кавычки, из-за чего вся команда считается именем запускаемого файла.

PS: На хероку используется линукс, а у тебя, вероятно, виндоуз, а у них есть различия в парсинге команд.